# Play 2 template not recognizing code, printing it instead

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to output the items in a List object to XML on the screen using Scala. I am trying to use the following code:

```
@(suppliers: List[Supplier])

@import helper._
@import scala.xml._

@main("Suppliers and Parts") {

    var xmlSuppliers = <suppliers>{ suppliers.map(s => s.toXml()) }</suppliers>
    println(xmlSuppliers)

}
```

But all that is happening is that those two lines of code are being written literally to the screen. They are not being interpreted.

I'm able to access the values of the suppliers list if i'm just using @supplier.id @supplier.name, etc. but i am wanting to output the List to XML on the screen and it's just not happening for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that is not scala but the templating engine of play. Have a look at [the documentation of the templating engine](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaTemplates). You need to mark your scala code as scala code. Your `@main` method expects a `Html` node and not a scala method.

Comment: Thanks, got it all up and working. Got a grip on it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either to wrap your code in a `@{}` block, or rewrite your code the *template* way:

```
<suppliers>
    @suppliers.map { s => @s.toXml() }
</suppliers>
```